# Joining another database into SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to join another database into my query in access as shown

```
LEFT JOIN  [X:\Zodds and Ends\Emer\T2Data.MDB].tblContacts 
ON EeDetails.BankCode = tblContacts.FirstName)
```

I am changing this query over to SQL Server but I cant find a way of linking the database I have also tried this but it doesn't work.

```
LEFT JOIN T2Ddata..tblContacts ON EeDetails.BankCode = tblContacts.FirstName)
```

Comment: Could you give some more context?

Comment: I think you just need to use the following syntax : 
LEFT JOIN Database.Schema.Table ON ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `LEFT JOIN databasename.schemaname.tablename`

The default schema is dbo. So it is usually: `databasename.dbo.tablename`

Also, it is a good idea to use an alias

```
LEFT JOIN T2Ddata.dbo.tblContacts c ON c.id = e.ContactId)
```

I doubt if you would be joining on FirstName?